# Is there a way to bind more than one style value in vue.js

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js

I want so make a div who's box shadow values can be changed using a slider but I can't seem to use more than one value stored in a data variable. Is there any way that I can do this?

```
<div :style="{ borderRadius: x_axis y_axis blur + 'px' spread color }" ></div>
```

---

Vue data:

```
data: {
  x_axis: 0,
  y_axis: 0,
  blur: 10,
  spread: 0,
  color: rgba(0,0,0,0.1)
}
```

Comment: Do you mean to use `boxShadow` instead of `borderRadius` in your template?

Comment: you should separate each property by semicolon

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can just use string interpolation using [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals). I strongly recommend you abstracting all that logic into a computed property, which makes your template way more readable:

```
<div :style="styleObject"></div>
```

Then, as a computed property, it will look like the following. I recommend suffixing `px` to all length properties, so that you don't run into errors if the values are non-zero (assuming you *intend* them to be pixel values):

```
computed: {
    styleObject() {
        return {
            boxShadow: `${this.x_axis}px ${this.y_axis}px ${this.blur}px ${this.spread}px ${this.color}`
        };
    }
}
```

You can even make it multiline ([template literals allow line breaks](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#multi-line_strings)) to make things a wee bit more readable:

```
computed: {
    styleObject() {
        return {
            boxShadow: `${this.x_axis}px
                           ${this.y_axis}px
                           ${this.blur}px
                           ${this.spread}px
                           ${this.color}`
        };
    }
}
```